# Cascading select list default value not set Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Getting an issue with cascading select list. Default value of a cascading select list is not set, not being displayed. 
I have a select list named  P3_ENTITY that is cascading and having 3 parents: P3_APPLICATION, P3_SCHEMA_LIST  and a checkbox P3_CATEGORY_CHECKBOX

I set the default value of P3_ENTITY in a Plsql process SET_VALUE that gets fired on page rendering. 
Process code is like :

```
BEGIN

:P3_ENTITY := :F100_FILTER_ENTITY;

END;
```

Now P3_ENTITY select list takes time to be loaded at the time of page load, but as execution of process SET_VALUE becomes completed before load of P3_ENTITY select list, that default value gets overwritten by NULL after full load of that select list.

Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To set cascading parents to a list implies that each time that the parents change, the list will be refreshed, this does not cause the re execution of the plsql block that you defined to set a default value.

What you could do, is create a dynamic action that execute your plsql block on an  **After Refresh** basis, this means that once the refresh event is complete the dynamic action will assign the :F100_FILTER_ENTITY value again.

Comment: Hi Typo,the thing is I dont wanna set default after every refresh of select list. at the time of loading the page, the select list takes time 5-6 seconds to load all the options in it executing the query, but before completing this select list refresh, that plsql block sets sets default value prior to refresh of that select list. So when select list is refreshed and loaded successfully, it sets the default value as null and overwrites the actual default value set by that page rendering PLSQL process

Comment: I just want to set the default value at the time of page load.. so that after loading the page default value is displayed on that select list... (when user has not changed anything yet on that select list)

Comment: Can you guide me how to create a dynamic action that works like,  at the time of loading that page after completion of loading of that cascading select list only, some plsql block or some statement to assign value will be executed.  It will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @TKD set the execution point of the dynamic action to "On Page Load", but still, if the cascading parents change, the select list will be refreshed and the default value wont be set.